# Почему в окне приложения не выводится DEUS VULT?

Tags: python, eel

уважаемые пользователи Stack Overflow. Вследствие просмотра видеоролика, у меня возник вопрос. Почему в окне не написано DEUS VULT? Дело в том, что я переписал код из видео, несколько редактировав его - что выводит на экран данная программа, название окна, а также изменил иконку окна на свою. Однако что-то пошло не так. Chrome установлен, ранее это повлияло на открытие моего окна, так как ранее код совсем не работал. Может, мне стоило как-то иначе гуглить? В любом случае - хочу услышать ваш ответ на данную тему. Благодарю.
В файле main.py указано следующее:

```
import eel

eel.init('web')#папка с интерфейсом программы

eel.start('main.html', size=(700, 700))
```

А в файле main.html я написал вот такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Torchery</title>

    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/torchery.png">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>DEUS VULT</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Результат кода]

Comment: А вопрос-то где?

Comment: Почему-то ничего не вывело, в отличие от результата в видеоролике.

Comment: Где лежит main.html? Что в консоли?

Comment: В папке web, которая находится в папке с проектом, названной Torchery.

Comment: По поводу видеоролика, нужно его убрать, он к вопросу отношения не имеет, нечего ему просмотры накручивать)

Comment: В консоли вот что: (base) D:\Рабочий стол\Visual Studio Code Python проекты\Torchery>D:/Anaconda_package/ Мой путь.

Comment: Вероятно, стоит поискать какой-нибудь более качественный источник информации, чем видео-уроки.

Comment: Хорошо, поищу. Спасибо.

Comment: В репозитории самого [eel](https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel) есть папка examples. Ну и readme.md довольно подробный)